# Gurobi installation issue

Tags: owl, protege, fuzzy-logic

I've installed Gurobi to make it possible to use fuzzy DL reasoner in protege.
below error issue after pressing solve button in protege fuzzy tab:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no GurobiJni65 in java.library.path

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no GurobiJni65 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at gurobi.GurobiJni.<clinit>(GurobiJni.java:198)
        at gurobi.GRBEnv.<init>(GRBEnv.java:16)
        at gurobi.GRBEnv.<init>(GRBEnv.java:11)
        at fuzzydl.milp.MILPHelper.solveGurobi(MILPHelper.java:701)
        at fuzzydl.milp.MILPHelper.optimize(MILPHelper.java:84)
        at fuzzydl.KnowledgeBase.optimize(KnowledgeBase.java:7870)
        at fuzzydl.MinInstanceQuery.solve(MinInstanceQuery.java:44)
        at FuzzyOWL2Plugin.FuzzyDLReasonerQueryPanel.solveButtonPressed(FuzzyDLReasonerQueryPanel.java:719)
        at FuzzyOWL2Plugin.FuzzyDLReasonerQueryPanel.access$2(FuzzyDLReasonerQueryPanel.java:605)
        at FuzzyOWL2Plugin.FuzzyDLReasonerQueryPanel$2.actionPerformed(FuzzyDLReasonerQueryPanel.java:162)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Uncaught Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0
```

I'm running win10 protege 4.3 Gurobi7.5.2 (no license is installed yet)

Comment: FuzzyDL is looking for the libraries corresponding to Gurobi version 6.5

Comment: @AKSW thanks.it solved. please write your comment as an answer